# Service with class method

Tags: ros, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I simply want to advertise a service from my main() using a class method as the callback.:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "conversion");//Init the ROS node
ros::NodeHandle nh;//Get the node handle

//My code (issue):
convert_pos2lin asd;//Create the object
ros::ServiceServer srv_ = nh.advertiseService("pos2lin", &convert_pos2lin::convert, &asd);

//The example code which works fine:
AddTwo a;
ros::ServiceServer ss = nh.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &AddTwo::add, &a);

ROS_INFO("Ready.");
ros::spin();

return 0;
```

Where the class method has the signature:

```
bool convert(scibot_control::srv_conversion::Request &req, scibot_control::srv_conversion::Response &res);
```

Despite reading the tutorials and such on this, i have been unable to do so.
I am always met with the build error - no matching function for call to advertiseService...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214597/service-with-class-method/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2015-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-26**:
Please upload the whole source file somewhere like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and also add the error log. It is a bit difficult to tell what can be the problem from the snippets you gave.

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2015-07-26**:\

- The service server: [conversion.cpp](http://pastebin.com/p41pYE6P)
- The service file: [srv_conversion.srv](http://pastebin.com/46UkMGyj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All versions of `NodeHandle::advertiseService()` function are templated (except for one) and template magic fails to deduce the right types. That happens because `convert()` can be found in the base class, while the object itself is of derived class. So, as I understand, compiler comes to the following substitution (**Note T1 and T2**):

```
advertiseService (const std::string &service, bool(T1::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T2 *obj)
```

while `NodeHandle` class has only the prototypes that expect the `srv_func` parameter to belong to the same type of object, as passed with `obj`, i.e.

```
advertiseService (const std::string &service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T *obj)
```

What you can do here is explicitly cast the pointer to the base class:

```
ros::ServiceServer srv_ = nh.advertiseService("pos2lin", &convert_pos2lin::convert, (convert*) &asd);
```

To make sure virtual functions are overloaded properly (if you have any), here is a small demo based on modified [AddTwoInts tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks#Service_Servers):

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "roscpp_tutorials/TwoInts.h"

class Base
{
public:
  virtual bool add(roscpp_tutorials::TwoInts::Request& req,
                   roscpp_tutorials::TwoInts::Response& res)
  {
    res.sum = op(req.a, req.b);
    ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
    ROS_INFO("  sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);

    return true;
  }

  virtual int op(int a, int b)
  {
    ROS_INFO("calling base op()");
    return a + b;
  }
};

class AddTwo: public Base
{
public:
  virtual int op(int a, int b)
  {
    ROS_INFO("calling derived op()");
    return a - b;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  AddTwo a;
  ros::ServiceServer ss = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &AddTwo::add, (Base*) &a);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2015-07-26**:
Yes, that was correct!

Thank you for your help - I wouldn't have considered the downcast...